# How to create an InputTextBox in visual c++ form

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

Say for example a user click a button to edit something I wound like a box to pop telling them to insert what they want to edit.

Comment: What is your question? Also, your tags contradict your comments to Jeeva's answer.

Answer (score 1):

If it is VC++ and you are using MFC then what you need to do is create a [DialogBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/619z63f5%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) with edit control in it and show the dialog box for the user to enter value.

If it is windows form try this

```
 Form f = new Form();
 f.ShowDialog(this);
```

Comment: I am using windows form application...not mfc

Comment: are you using c++/clr? please be specific and elaborate which tools you are using?

Comment: c++ I am using the window for application in visual studio c++

Comment: @Jeeva: Does this have **EDIT BOX**?